# Problem with implementing https in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, oauth-2.0

I tried to make an oauth server with separate resource server but I can't have a connection between them.

OAuth2Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Value("${logistics.oauth.tokenTimeout:36000}")
    private int expiration;

    @Value("${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private String resourceIds;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    private String keystore;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}")
    private String alias;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

        configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("logistics").secret(passwordEncoder().encode("secret")).accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
                .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token","authorization_code").resourceIds(resourceIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices(){
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());}

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(){

        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(keystore);
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(resource,password.toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(alias));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer(){return new CustomTokenEnhancer();}

}
```

WebsecurityConfig OAut2Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=81

server.ssl.key-alias=alias
server.ssl.key-store-type=jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks

server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
INCLUDE_ANY_OTHER_ONES_YOU_NEED_TO_SUPPORT
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've followed multiple tutorials but none of them worked. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is there any error you are in seeing logs??

Comment: Nope the application is starting normally. But when I do a postman post request it's saying that the server is down.

Comment: Can you please show your server starting logs and error response you get from api..

Comment: Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:81/authentication/oauth/token.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Comment: He can't get any response

Comment: Starting logs:2018-10-11 16:37:00.731  INFO 13372 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 81 (https)
 2018-10-11 16:37:00.905  INFO 13372 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.o.o.Oauth2serverApplication          : Started Oauth2serverApplication in 12.754 seconds (JVM running for 14.585)

Comment: Can use port 8443 and check

Comment: In postman are you using https://localhost:81 if not work then please run app on 8443 and check

Comment: Unfortunately didn't change that anything

Comment: would you mind sharing your sample project on GitHub so I can look at..